# css asterisk selector support

Tags: css, selector

is this a legitimate use of * selector, and if so are there references to how browsers support this? it seems to work in all browsers I have test, but I haven't used older ones or IE

```
body * {
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is! The asterisk is a wildcard, it will select all elements within that DOM element you set it to.

For example, if I you want to apply an attribute to your whole site:

```
* {
    attribute: value;
}
```

Or as you did it with a special DOM element!

```
 element * {
     attribute: value;
    }
```

You could also use something like:

```
* { 
     attribute: value;
  }

* * { ... }

* * * { ... }

* div * { ... }
```

Which is a bit difficult... like a recursion.

Comment: but note that `* *` provides no benefit over `*`, since the latter already selects all dom elements, not just top level.

Comment: Depends on how to style!
* { border:1px solid red } for all top level elements
* * { border:2px dotted green } for all subelements of every top level element... so it MIGHT be usefull! ;)

Comment: except that `* *` also selects the top level elements.  http://jsfiddle.net/9mUKV/1/

Comment: That is not correct, if you use it correct you can see that it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/jB3jX/ except that the outer element also gets a green border in addition!

Comment: How is that different than my example.  You just proved your own statement false, your "top level element" gets your "secondary selector" too.

Comment: Sorry, I was regarding on your statment: 
"but note that * * provides no benefit over *"
Maybe just a misunderstanding!? :)

Comment: how good of a practice is this though? I have heard people say that it is a really bad practice to use * maybe they just don't understand the concept?

Comment: my styles have been really getting lots of bad practices, so trying to clean it up and find best use cases.

Comment: It really depends on the concept of your layout and html! You might have many unique elements which all have to be defined. In the end you could also work with classes, but what if you want all div in your body having a border of 2px and just some have an expection with 3 px. So you put the * for all div with 2px and the exceptions get the class attribute with the 3 px. This is mostly interesting for sth like a forum or a website with a lot of repeated items. In the end everony uses css as he wants. Its like programming. Everyone has his own style and everyone says his own is the best!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, but you should avoid the use of it. You can make it more clear. But if you really want all elements to float left it is a good way to do it. But why do you want this?

All browsers support this, source: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t10

Comment: *:focus
{
    outline: none;
} is just one use of it. I hate that chrome outlines things, so I added this to my reset css styles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your example is a legitimate, if not heavy-handed use of the `*` selector.  This will cause every child element of the body element to be floated left.

Comment: trying to clean up my css, that is why I am using it. maybe this is wrong way of going about it? I have all my footer elements with float left on them, so It seemed redundant to have it in every one.

Comment: Then you might try something like `#footer * {...}` - (changing #footer to the appropriate selector) to target just those elements within footer.  That would/could be an excellent use of the `*` selector.  `body *` would be typically reserved for css resets (http://www.cssreset.com/), etc - but in reality, they are often applied at just the `*` level, without the `body` selector.